# RunBlocking with Dispatcher communication not working

Tags: android, kotlin, dispatcher, kotlin-coroutines

> I have switched my context to **Dispatcher.Main** to show UI but data fetched on runBlocking but unable to display in **RecylerView**

```
runBlocking {
            var fruits = fetchFruitList()
            withContext(Dispatchers.Main){
                recyclerView.adapter = FruitAdapter(fruits);
            }
        }
```

what am I doing wrong and what is the appropriate way to return data from one Dispatcher to another.

I have tried another way

```
GlobalScope.launch {
            withContext(Dispatchers.IO){
                var fruits = arrayOf("Grapes","Apple","Mango","TuttiFruit","PineApple",
                        "Pomegrante","Apple","Mango","TuttiFruit","PineApple",
                        "Pomegrante","Apple","Mango","TuttiFruit","PineApple").toList()
                return@withContext
            }
            recyclerView.adapter = FruitAdapter(fruits)
        }
```

but in above way `I have to declare fruits as global` whereas I don't want to have it global to work. Is there a way to return data from one 'dispatcher queue to another

> I have to fetch data from Api (IO operation) and display that data in RecyclerView(Main Thread Operation)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you must switch the context after the data is fetched:

```
GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO){
       var fruits = arrayOf("Grapes","Apple","Mango","TuttiFruit","PineApple",
                    "Pomegrante","Apple","Mango","TuttiFruit","PineApple",
                    "Pomegrante","Apple","Mango","TuttiFruit","PineApple").toList()

       withContext(Dispatchers.MAIN){
           recyclerView.adapter = FruitAdapter(fruits)
       }        
}
```

Edit According to the comments:

For the `runBlocking` check out the documentation first paragraph.

> Runs a new coroutine and blocks the current thread interruptibly until
>   its completion. This function should not be used from a coroutine. It
>   is designed to bridge regular blocking code to libraries that are
>   written in suspending style, to be used in main functions and in
>   tests.

Secondly, you ask for the `GlobalScope` usage. Yea, if you are doing coroutines in Android you should avoid that. [Reasons here](https://medium.com/@elizarov/the-reason-to-avoid-globalscope-835337445abc).

How to launch a coroutine in Android Activity/Fragment?

First I suggest to use in the `ViewModel` or the `Presenter` but if you want to launch a coroutine in the Activity/Fragment, you will need a way to control and manage it's cancellation to avoid memory leak.
The solution for this would be:

```
private val job: Job = Job()
                                              //or Dispatchers.IO
private val fragmentScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.MAIN + job)

//launch a coroutine later in Activity/Fragment

fragmentScope.launch{
  //the default coroutine dispatcher would be the defined dispatcher above
}

override fun onDestroy(){
  super.onDestroy()
  fragmentScope.cancel()
}
```

As for your question:

> what am I doing wrong and what is the appropriate way to return data
>   from one Dispatcher to another

You can also try this solution if you want to return values from a different context:

```
someScope.launch(Dispatchers.MAIN){
 var data = withContext(Dispatchers.IO){
  val someData = fetchSomeData()
  return@withContext data
}
if(data.isAvailable()){ //for example
 //runing on the main thread
 }
}
```

Comment: And I have learn I should not use GlobalScope . So what other scope should I use. I tried to use launch direct but it is missing in activity why?

Comment: I appreciate your effort. One last point why we add CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main + SupervisorJob()) two values in a CoroutineScope e.g Main and a job??

Comment: Sorry about that: that's a `+` not a `=` first. But second, the job is the way you need to take control of the operations (to access and manage them) and the coroutine scope is just a way to tell that our coroutine context has a job and it's running in some Dispatchers.MAIN. It's just a Kotlin thing, the `+`